# How to shuffle order of command in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, command, shuffle

Like in the title, i want to shuffle order of command ,

```
a = [print("something"),print("another_thing")]
import random
random.shuffle(a)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [Lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
comms = [lambda: print("something"), lambda: print("another_thing")]
```

Shuffle the items as you did:

```
random.shuffle(comms)
```

Then call the items (and collect the results):

```
results = list(comm() for comm in comms)
```